# Is `log_bin` necessary on slave in master-slave MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7

I'm running out of disk space on a slave due to MySQL binary logs (`mysql-bin.000xxx`) being stored on the slave.

Here's the relevant portion of the slave's `my.cnf`:

```
binlog_format  = mixed
log_bin        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sync_binlog    = 1
```

I'm currently catching up to Master, so I expect to see a bunch of `mysql-relay-bin.00xxxx`'s on Slave, but I'm not sure why it also needs `mysql-bin.000xxx`'s.

The Master also has a lot of `mysql-bin.000xxx`'s, but I expect it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the slave is not a master to other slaves, then you do not need binary logging on the slave

To reclaim the space of those logs on the Slave immediately, run this

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
mysql> RESET MASTER;
mysql> START SLAVE;
```

This will hose all binary logs on the Slave.

You could then remove or comment out log_bin from the my.cnf of the Slave and restart mysqld

Comment: Does `RESET MASTER;` impact the slave's position with the real master? In other words, if the slave is catching up on a certain file and position, does `RESET MASTER` reset that as well? (Because that's not what I want at all)

Comment: Not at all. The slave position to the Master is in the relay logs, not its local binary logs. Naturally, you do not want to run RESET MASTER on a Master, ever !!!